# Naive matrix multiplication improvement

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, matrix

My CS teacher asked us to "add a small change" to this code to make it run with time complexity of **N<sup>3</sup> - N<sup>2</sup>** instead of the normal **N<sup>3</sup>**. I cannot for the life of me figure it out and I was wondering if anyone happened to know. I don't think he is talking about strassens method. 
from when I looked at it, maybe it could take advantage of the fact that he only cares about a square (diagonal) matrix.

```
void multiply(int n, int A[][], int B[][], int C[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very imprecise. What's "time complexity?" E.g. a machine with N processors can multiply matrices in O(N^2) time. Run time depends on the machine model. Conventionally the efficiency of matrix algorithms is measured in arithmetic ops on the matrix elements. Your teacher is probably expecting you to notice that you can save N^2 additions by changing `C[i][j] = 0` to `C[i][j] = A[i][0] * B[0][j]` and then starting the inner `for` loop with `k = 1`.  In practice this is dumb. A good compiler will do it for you as part of a loop unrolling optimization.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot achieve Matrix multiplication in **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**. However, you can improve the complexity from **O(N<sup>3</sup>)**. In linear algebra, there are algorithms like the [Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) which reduces the time complexity to **O(N<sup>2.8074</sup>)** by reducing the number of multiplications required for each 2x2 sub-matrix from 8 to 7.

An improved version of the [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) is the fastest known matrix multiplication algorithm with the best time complexity of **O(N<sup>2.3729</sup>)**.